# Use of "the" in sentences--when is it redundant?

Tags: grammaticality, grammar

1. He played with the items in the house.
2. He played with items in the house.
3. Target the addictions that plague your life.
4. Target addictions that plague your life.

What exactly is the effect of removing "the" in such sentences? I've had it crossed out a couple of times now, but I'm not sure which ones I should edit away from my sentences.  Is either sentence wrong? Is the sentence without "the" better?

Answer (score 2):

The use of English article is best understood in the context in which they occur, and that, of course, is lacking in isolated sentences, so read the following comments with that in mind.

The definite article is used when there is some shared knowledge between the writer and reader. In your first sentence we must assume that both are aware that there were indeed some items in the house for him to play with. Similarly, in your third sentence, there is an assumption that that there are some addictions that plague your life.

When an article is absent, it is sometimes said that the *zero* article is being used, as is the case in your second and fourth sentences. The zero article is typically used with uncountable nouns and plural countable nouns to make a non-specific or generic reference. In your second sentence, we are not told which specific items he played with. All we know is that they were in the house. In your fourth sentence, the addictions are also non-specific. (Sentences 3 and 4 are complicated by the question of defining and non-defining relative clauses.)

The use of the English articles is something that learners of English have difficulty with, particularly if the concept of articles is new. You really need to consult your teacher, if you have one, or the relevant section of a grammar book designed for foreign learners. (Forgive me if you are a native speaker, but this is just the kind of question that foreign learners often ask.)

Answer (score 1):

Some readers may consider the inclusion of *the* to encompass the universe of the things described, and the omission of *the* to refer to either all or a subset of the total group.

The difference is subtle and far from definitive, so in most cases, either would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.

First, you seemed unsure of the cases in which 'the' had been crossed out in your writing. I think I might have discovered a key, illustrated in the examples you provided.

Let's consider the first pair of sentences (1 and 2):

He played with the items in the house.
He played with items in the house.

'In the house' already identifies the items in question, i.e., the ones to be found in *the* house to which the sentence refers. Said items therefore don't need to be singled out among all items yet again with 'the'.

In the second pair of questions (3 and 4), the same principle applies. Which addictions are being spoken about? The ones that 'plague your life'. Hence, in the first of the second pair of questions, 'addictions' are being singled out twice, by 'the' and by '[that] plague your life'.

So, that might be why you've had the word 'the' crossed out in your writing.

You also wanted to know the effect of removing 'the' in such sentences. I think that it blurs focus. You see, 'the' identifies things the writer believes both he and the reader know the identity of. 'The items in the house' connotes specificity-*which items in particular in the house* (and note I say 'connotes', because the items aren't really identified, but they appear to be). Alternatively, 'the items' could be *all* the items found in the house. 'He played with items in the house' on the other hand seems less specific-he could be playing with any of the items found in the house.

The same is true with 'the addictions that plague your life'. A specific set of addictions are being identified-all the ones that 'plague your life'. On the other hand, if you tell someone to deal with 'addictions that plague your life', you'd be speaking more generally, i.e., of any of the addictions that *could* plague or *might be* plaguing their life.